# ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPPasswordIsMandatoryError: password is mandatory in simple bind

Tags: python, flask, ldap3

I am trying to set up authentication with `flask` and `ldap3`. For this I have a global_authentication.py, a main.py in which I create Flask and perform the view, as well as a loginform.py where the template for the login is located, a login.html and a _formhelper.html. When I start the Flask server a login screen appears with the login data. When I enter login info I get the following error message:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPPasswordIsMandatoryError: password is mandatory in simple bind
```

Furthermore it refers to the lines:

```
File "D:\Projects\admin_tool\Logic\main.py", line 49, in index
login_msg = global_ldap_authentication(login_id, login_password)
```

and file

```
"D:\Projects\admin_tool\Logic\views\global_ldap_authentication.py", line 34, in global_ldap_authentication if not connection.bind():
```

Can anyone help me with this? Unfortunately, I can't find a solution and have searched the entire Internet.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, g, session
import os
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from views.global_ldap_authentication import *
from forms.LoginForm import *
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask.sessions import SecureCookieSessionInterface
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer
from flask_restx import Namespace,Resource,fields
import requests
import json


app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')

bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False



@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
 
    # initiate the form..
    form = LoginValidation()
 
    if request.method in ('POST') :
        login_id = form.user_name_pid.data
        login_password = form.user_pid_Password.data
 
        # create a directory to hold the Logs
        login_msg = global_ldap_authentication(login_id, login_password)
 
        # validate the connection
        if login_msg == "Success":
            success_message = f"*** Authentication Success "
            return render_template('success.html', success_message=success_message)
 
        else:
            error_message = f"*** Authentication Failed - {login_msg}"
            return render_template("error.html", error_message=str(error_message))
 
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)



@app.route('/hello')
class HelloResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"message":"Hello World"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**global_ldap_authentication.py**

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, SUBTREE from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPException, LDAPBindError
    def global_ldap_authentication(user_name, user_pwd):
    """
      Function: global_ldap_authentication
       Purpose: Make a connection to encrypted LDAP server.
       :params: ** Mandatory Positional Parameters
                1. user_name - LDAP user Name
                2. user_pwd - LDAP User Password
       :return: None
    """
 
    # fetch the username and password
    ldap_user_name = user_name
    ldap_user_pwd = user_pwd
 
    # ldap server hostname and port
    ldsp_server = f"ldap://localhost:389"
 
    # dn
    root_dn = "dc=example,dc=org"
 
    # user
    user = f'cn={ldap_user_name},{root_dn}'
 
    print(user)
    server = Server(ldsp_server, get_info=ALL)
 
    connection = Connection(server,
                            user=user,
                            password=ldap_user_pwd)
    if not connection.bind():
        print(f" *** Cannot bind to ldap server: {connection.last_error} ")
        l_success_msg = f' ** Failed Authentication: {connection.last_error}'
    else:
        print(f" *** Successful bind to ldap server")
        l_success_msg = 'Success'
 
    return l_success_msg
```

**LoginForm.py**

```
from main import app
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, validators


class LoginValidation(Form):
    user_name_pid = StringField('', [validators.DataRequired()],
                                render_kw={'autofocus': True, 'placeholder': 'Enter User'})

    user_pid_Password = PasswordField('', [validators.DataRequired()],
                             

     render_kw={'autofocus': True, 'placeholder': 'Enter your login Password'})
```

**login.html**

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post>
  <dl>
    {{ render_field(form.user_name_pid) }}
    {{ render_field(form.user_pid_Password) }}
  </dl>
  <p><input type=submit value=Login>
</form>
```

**_formhelpers.html**

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Have you printed `login_password` to be sure it isn't blank?

Comment: You're right, i printed login_password  and it is blank. However, i can't explain this either. why does this happen?

Comment: `form = LoginValidation()` You aren't passing the POST data to the form.  You're just creating a blank empty form.

Comment: Hey, thanks first of all for your answer. Tried it now as follows: <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal needs-validation" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">. However, I only get this output for the password with a print: Password: None
cn=None,dc=example,dc=org

Comment: I don't think you understood.  To create the form object, the documentation says to do it like this `form = LoginValidation(request.POST)`, which allows the form to fill in the submitted data.  But you did this `form = LoginValidation()`, which means you create just an empty blank form with no data filled in.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Unfortunately when I create the object form with LoginValidation(request.POST) it still doesn't work.  I still get an error message: AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST'.